# Migrate from wicket 1.4 to 1.5 now not able to import packages

Tags: groovy, wicket-1.5, wicket-1.4

I have a project I built in Wicket 1.4.  When I moved to 1.5 to take advantage of the IEvent feature, suddenly I can't compile because the wicket java pages can't see the packages of my service tier.  My service tier is built in groovy 2.0.0, though I doubt that this is the problem.  I must be missing something obvious.  Below are my dependencies:
where wicket version is 1.5.7

```
       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-ioc</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

my imports are well...imports

Comment: I think we'll need to see a bit more info before there's any hope of helping here.  At least some of the compile errors...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help Don, but it turns out I had made a change to my pom file where I removed the `<goal>generateStubs</goal>
                            <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>`

from my gmaven plugin executions.  The problem didn't surface since I hadn't made a change in my groovy code and then when I did make a change it wasn't compiling the groovy code at all which is what led to the absence of the groovy packages.  It just happened to coincide with my wicket version change.